# Limit of connections between unix sockets and tcp/ip

Tags: networking, sysctl

I have a server with the following sysctl settings:

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 50000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 2000000
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15
net.core.somaxconn = 65535
```

Yet my nginx at peak traffic complains about connecting to my php-fpm unix sockets.

```
2021/09/30 17:06:24 [error] 1848498#1848498: *32855016 connect() to unix:/var/php/streamer.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 100.1.1.3
```

I can't find if I'm at maximum value possible or if it's possible to increase more, if I should change to TCP/IP or etc. All traffic to this server is served via another instance over wireguard so the client is always 100.1.1.3

Also a answer that shows how to know how much of those resources you are really using would sure help a lot of people googling about this

Comment: That's just a guess, but could you change whatever program is *listening* to that `/var/php/streamer.sock` to call `listen(2)` with a larger `backlog` argument?

Comment: Look for `listen.backlog` in `php-fpm.conf` and see if setting it to something larger fixes that issue. Maybe you're lucky ;-)

Comment: About Uncle Billy's setting, `ss -lxn src == /var/php/streamer.sock` should display the values in use: backlog in Send-Q, "in the pipeline"/pending in Recv-Q. if Recv-Q > Send-Q, there's one or more connection(s) that can potentially fail.  (those fields show different information on the LISTEN entry, normally it's about pending *data* , rather than pending connections)